# Define time limit using Log4j2 in configuration properties

Tags: java, logging, time, configuration, log4j2

This is configuration parameters below,which are belongs to the log4j2 library.

```
status=all
name=PropertiesConfig
#Make sure to change log file path as per your need
property.filename=C:\\logs\\sms.log
filters=threshold
filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level=all
appenders=rolling
appender.rolling.type=RollingFile
appender.rolling.name=RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName=${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern=C:\\logs\\sms-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type=Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval=1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate=true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
#appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max=20
loggers=rolling
logger.rolling.name=com.company.Main
logger.rolling.level=all
logger.rolling.additivity=true
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile
```

and the following code write logging messages up to 30 seconds. When it reaches 30 seconds, the process is terminated and created the new file in the logs folder. What I want to do here is first I want to set my time limit to 30 seconds in my Log4j2 configuration properties file and the reason I  do this is because I want to create a new file after 30 seconds and check if it will write my logging messages there.

```
    String s1 = "test";
    String s2 = "test";


    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + 30 * 1000;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        LOG.info(s1);
        LOG.info(s2);
    }
```

In short, in my Log4j2 properties file, I first want my time limit to be 30 seconds and on the code side, I want the loop to loop 2 times. I want to check that when the first 30 seconds are over, it will create a new file and write a message to the new file in the next 30 seconds.

How can I set my time limit to 1 day in my configuration file? The reason why I do this is that I want to check that when 1 day is over, when it switches to the next day, it will create a new file and write logging messages there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `appender.rolling.filePattern=C:\\logs\\sms-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log`  .

The pattern you gave has `HH-mm-sss` in it . So when you restart the service/server again, a new file is created for that time frame.

If you want to write to one file per day, remove `HH-mm-ss` from `filePattern` and try.

Like this `appender.rolling.filePattern=C:\\logs\\sms-%d{MM-dd-yy}-%i.log` .

Comment: Yes, it worked. When I terminate the project and run it again, it writes messages to the same file without creating a new file. But, how do I know that when I switch to the new day, it will create a new file and write messages there?

Comment: Glad it helped.Please upvote my answer if it helped you

Comment: I'm thinking of doing something like this using threads. I want to set the time limit to 5 minutes in my configuration file and then print the logging messages every 5 minutes. If it takes more than 5 minutes, I want it to create a new file and write it there, how can I do that?

Comment: And how can I set the 5 minutes process in the configuration file?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to implement it. Please follow this link . It may help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858022/how-to-configure-a-log4j-file-appender-which-rolls-the-log-file-every-15-minutes